# All the numbers with exactly 8 divisors

Tags: java, numbers, factors

Given `n`, I need the number of numbers which have exactly 8 divisors.

```
24 = 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 24
```

Below `100` there are 10 numbers which satisfy the above condition.

`24, 30, 40, 42, 54, 56, 66, 70, 78 and 88`.

Given n, How many numbers satisfy the above condition below `n`.

**The First Approach:**

I used the prime factors approach.

```
x = p1^k1 * p2 ^k2 * p3^k3 ...
n = (k1 + 1)(k2 + 1)(k3 + 1)...
```

This approach is a bit slow when dealing with large numbers.

```
int max = 1000000000;
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < max; ++i)
   if(check(i))count++;

private static boolean check(int num) {
    int ans = 1;
    int count = 0;
    while (num % 2 == 0) {
        num /= 2;
        count++;
    }
    ans *= (count + 1);
    if (ans > 8)
        return false;
    for (int i = 3; i * i <= num; ++i) {
        count = 0;
        while (num % i == 0) {
            count++;
            num /= i;
        }
        ans *= (count + 1);
        if (ans > 8)
            return false;
    }
    if (num != 1)
        ans *= 2;
    if (ans > 8)
        return false;
    return ans == 8;
}
```

**The second approach:**

Sieve similar method, which marks all the multiples of a number and then check if the count is `8` or not.

```
static int max = 100000000;
static int[] facs = new int[max];

for (int i = 2; i < max; ++i) {
    for (int j = i; j < max; j += i) {
        facs[j]++;
    }
}
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < max; ++i)
    if (facs[i] == 7)//1 is a factor of all number so check for count 7
        count++;
System.out.println(count);
```

However this approach is a bit faster but this cannot be used for bigger numbers above `10^9`.

How do I calculate the numbers which have exactly 8 divisors above `10^9`?

Is there any trick that I'm missing? How can I improve this?

Comment: Given a (precalculated) list of primes, one do all 8 combinations below n, a bit intelligently.

Comment: @JoopEggen That is wonderful! Thanks.

Comment: I think you can use long (64 bit) type.

Comment: A number has exactly `8` divisors if it is a prime number to the power `7` (e.g. `2^7 = 128`) or if it is the cube of a prime multiplied by a different prime (e.g. `24 = 2^3 * 3`). This may help speed things up.

Comment: With the first approach, you correctly identified how you can calculate the number of divisors from the prime factorisation. Now, the question is: what form should the prime factorization have for a number to have exactly 8 divisors?

Comment: Ah, @PaulBoddington spoiled the answer. (Though his answer isn't fully correct either. :)

Comment: @PaulBoddington Because you forgot about the `p1*p2*p3` form.

Comment: @biziclop You're right. It can also be a three different prime number multiplied together. Bad mistake.

Comment: @biziclop perfect! all 3 pair prime multiples, (8 = 2 * 2 * 2)

Comment: But taking this avenue slightly further: given that we now know all the candidates are in the form `p1*p2*p3`, `p1^3 * p2` or `p^7`, what is the biggest `p` that can appear in such a number? (In terms of `n`.)

Comment: @biziclop `for p1*p2*p3 - n/p1*p2 for p1^3 * p2 - n / p1^3 and for p^7 n^1/7`, so the maximum value of these would be the largest `p`. For 10^12, the largest `p` would be around `1666666666666`, calculating primes for such a big number is a very tedious task. Also the number of iterations are almost nCx, both n and x are large. Am I missing something?

Comment: @UmaKanth Correct. But you're already better off by at least a factor of 6 and listing primes using a sieve is a well-researched area. Unfortunately you can't really go much better than that because you must know all the potential prime divisors.

Comment: Solving this problem with `max = 10^12` is really, really hard. To find all numbers of form `2 * 3 * p`, you'd have to count all prime numbers up to `10^12 / 6 == 166666666666` (I think you have too many sixes). On my machine, simply looping over these values in a `for` loop with an empty body: `for (long a = 0; a < 166666666666L; a++);` took 133 seconds. So even with a clever sieve method, this is going to be unbelievably hard to do quickly.

Comment: @PaulBoddington That's right, I thought of an another way with which this can be solved easily. Look at my answer to the question.

Comment: @PaulBoddington I agree, there's no way to solve the worst-case scenario without being able to enumerate all the primes below `N/6` first. And that's hard. However once you've done that, a lot of optimisations can be applied in the rest of the solution, which in themselves can be quite interesting.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point is to find the number of numbers, not the numbers which reduces the problem from the iterations to calculations.

For a number to have 8 divisors it should be either written in one of the 3 forms.

```
p1 * p2 * p3

p1^3 * p2

p^7
```

because, from the formula `8 = 2 * 2 * 2 or 4 * 2 or 8 * 1`

So If we know how many prime numbers are below `n`, we can find out the combinations that can have `8` divisors.

```
p1*p2*p3:

The maximum `p` can be `N / 2 * 3`.
So the number of numbers which have `8` divisors are nC3.

p1^3*p2:

The maximum `p` can be `N/8`.
So the number of numbers which have `8` divisors are nC2.

p^7:

The maximum `p` can be `N^(1/7)`.
So the number of numbers which have `8` divisors are `n`.

Here, `n` is the number of primes under `N`
```

So, to find out the `n` the number of primes under `N`,
we can use the [Prime Counting Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function) instead of calculating the primes.

So once you know the number of primes, you can calculate the number of numbers by selective combinations.

Comment: Unfortunately life isn't so simple. Let's say `N=1000`, and that we're looking for numbers that satisfy the second formula (`p1^3*p2`). `p1=7,p2=3` is over the limit, while `p1=3,p2=7` is not. So you can't just pick any two primes in any order. Worse than that, the prime counting function is unknown, all we have is rough approximations.